# editing footer text in JBST theme

Tags: footer

I'm a new WP user with a new site. The default theme footer is "© 2014 John Little Psychic Consultant". I'd like to add my city name so it reads "© 2014 John Little Psychic Consultant- Asheville NC".
Thanks

Comment: You can simply change the footer text from the Customizer Menu on Wp Admin. Just Follow - Wp admin -> Themes -> Customizer -> Footer Credits

Comment: Well, son of a gun! How easy was that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The footer credits are output by the `jbst_credits` custom action, which has the [`jbst_custom_credits()`](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/jbst/2.0.5/functions/jbst-footer-functions.php#L109) callback:

```
function jbst_custom_credits() {
    if(get_theme_mod('footer_credits') <> "") {echo    get_theme_mod('footer_credits');}
    else {?>
        <?php printf( __( '&copy;', 'jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme' )); ?> <?php echo date('Y');?> <?php echo bloginfo('name');?><span class="sep"> | </span><a target="_blank" href="<?php esc_attr_e( 'http://www.jbst.eu/', 'jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme' ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Powered by JBST', 'jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme' ); ?>" rel="generator"><?php printf( __( 'Powered by JBST', 'jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme' ), 'jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme' ); ?></a>
    <?php }
}

add_action('jbst_credits', 'jbst_custom_credits');
```